# I'm having a problem concatenating two columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

When I'm concatenating two columns of type String in my DataFrame it's giving me an error.

I'm taking the spaces out of it, is this way I'm doing it right?

My code, concat columns:

```
df_control['NAME'] = df_control['NAME'].astype(str)
df_control['LASTNAME'] = df_control['LASTNAME'].astype(str)
df_control['LASTNAME'] = df_control['LASTNAME'].str.split()
df_control['NAME'] = df_control['NAME'].str.split()

df_control['FULL NAME'] = df_control['NAME']+' '+df_control['LASTNAME']
```

Example:

```
0 NAME LASTNAME
1 Wilson  Nunes
```

Error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

Expected:

```
0 NAME LASTNAME  FULL NAME
1 Wilson  Nunes   Wilson  Nunes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `str.split` will return a list which you cannot concatenate with `' '`. It suffices to call columns:

```
df_control['FULL NAME'] = df_control['NAME'].astype(str) + ' ' + \
                          df_control['LASTNAME'].astype(str)
```

You don't even need `astype(str)` if the values in those columns were already strings:

```
df_control['NAME']+ ' '+ df_control['LASTNAME']
```

Answer (score 1):

all you need is this:

```
df_control['FULL NAME'] = df_control['NAME'].str.cat(df_control['LASTNAME'],' ')
```